# How do I prevent JAWS to say onmouseover in html

Tags: html, accessibility, onmouseover, jaws-screen-reader

I have code like this in HTML login page:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" onmouseover="hover(this, 1)" 
onmouseout="hover(this, 0)" value="Enter" name="feature=111" id="login-button">
```

Every time I come to the button with keyboard it says "Enter button onmouseover". How do I prevent it from saying onmouseover? I'm not looking for JAWS options, I'm looking for some optional attribute or something like that.

Comment: Only way to prevent it is to not use it. JAWS will always say it, maybe except on expert verbosity mode.

Comment: try not including it inline

Comment: Can you post your code for the hover() function? If you are using it for styling purposes only, you may want to consider the [css :hover pseudoselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) and removing the inline event handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the inline javascript:

```
<script>
  var button = document.findElementById('login-button');
  button.addEventListener('onmouseover', function(event) { hover(event.target, 1) });
  button.addEventListener('onmouseout', function(event) { hover(event.target, 0) });
</script>

<input type="submit" class="button" value="Enter" name="feature=111" id="login-button">
```

or use the [css :hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) pseudoselector if it the hover() function is just for styling.